# How to Authenticate with Firebase realtime database using UID or Email and Password for REST API using postman

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, postman, firebase-security

I used this protection rules in the database like this

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

In postman I tried GET with url.json but I get `permission denied` I tried to search the documentations how to find and pass current UID but could not find

Also for authentication with email and password I select in the postman Authorization "Basic Auth" and I went to firebase `Project settings` then I add member then I add email and select role "Firebase Admin" but where I get this user entered password to save it in postman ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the user's data via the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data), you'll have to make sure the calls are authenticated as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).

The options for this are to add a parameter to the request:

- either pass the OAuth2 token of a collaborator on the project in an `access_token` parameter,
- or pass the ID token of the correct Firebase Authentication user in an `auth` parameter.

There is no way to pass just the UID of the user, as that would not be secure - as anyone could pass any value for as their UID in that case.